# SearchHit hit.getSourceAsMap() return only 10 fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I use RestHighLevelClient to execute a query into an index, like this:

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(hostname, port, scheme))
                    .setPathPrefix(pathPrefix));
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

for (SearchHit hit : searchResponse.getHits()) {
        D dto = (D) objectMapper.readValue(
                hit.getSourceAsString(), //<-- only 10 field in _sources
                params.getDtoClass());

        ((List<D>) result.getResult()).add(dto);}
```

But only 10 field in _sources present, some result (hit.getSourceAsMap()) watch in debug.

[image]

Help me please, where is the problem?

query and params (from searchRequest.toString()):

```
SearchRequest{
searchType=QUERY_THEN_FETCH, 
indices=[], 
indicesOptions=IndicesOptions[
ignore_unavailable=false, 
allow_no_indices=true, 
expand_wildcards_open=true, 
expand_wildcards_closed=false, 
allow_aliases_to_multiple_indices=true, 
forbid_closed_indices=true, 
ignore_aliases=false, 
ignore_throttled=true], 
types=[], 
routing='null', 
preference='null', 
requestCache=null, 
scroll=null, 
maxConcurrentShardRequests=0, 
batchedReduceSize=512, 
preFilterShardSize=128, 
allowPartialSearchResults=null, 
localClusterAlias=null, 
getOrCreateAbsoluteStartMillis=-1, 
source={
  "from":0,
  "size":25,
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":[{
        "wildcard":{
          "s_inn":{
            "wildcard":"*111111*","boost":1.0
          }
        }
        },
        {
          "wildcard":{
            "s_ogrn":{
              "wildcard":"*11111*",
              "boost":1.0

            }
          }
        }
        ],
        "adjust_pure_negative":true,
        "boost":1.0
      }
    },
    "highlight":{"fields":{"s_name":{},"s_reg_num":{},"s_ogrn": },"s_inn":{}}}}}
```

This "query" by Postman return full expect fields

[image]

Comment: Add the query that you are sending to elastic.

Comment: add query and params from searchRequest.toString()